# Breaking up promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Why are these not equivalent and is there a way to make them so?

```
// Returns result of promiseB
var p = self.promiseA()
  .then(self.promiseB);
return p;


// Returns result of promiseA
var p = self.promiseA();
p.then(self.promiseB);
return p;
```

For example if I wanted to do something like:

```
var p = self.promiseA();

if(cond) {
  p.then(self.promiseB);
}
return p;
```

Comment: `.then` (and most promise methods) return a new promise - they do not `return this`, that's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first returns a combined promise (that will be resolved only when promiseA has been resolved and promiseB has been run).

In this first case, `p` is the result of running `self.promiseA().then();` which is a new promise beyond just what `self.promiseA()` returns.

---

The second returns only the first promise which is only what `self.promiseA()` returns.

---

One thing that isn't always obvious with `.then()` is that we think of it like it runs later after the promise before is fulfilled, but that isn't really what happens.  The entire `.then()` chain runs immediately.  Function pointers are stored away to be called later (when promises are fulfilled), but the entire chain runs immediately and each call to `.then()` creates a new promise that can have different fulfillment timing and result than the previous one in the chain (it depends upon what each `.then()` callback does when it gets called).

So `self.promiseA()` doesn't return the same thing as `self.promiseA.then(xxx)`.  The latter is a new promise that incorporates both the first promise and then result of running the `.then()` handler.

---

If you wanted to do your conditional, you could do this:

```
var p = self.promiseA();

if(cond) {
  p = p.then(self.promiseB);
}
return p;
```

If you're trying to return the accumulated or combined promise, then you need to return the result of `p.then()`, not just `p`.